# How to create an array of record counts, grouped by month, and maintain performance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails app, I have a User model and a Posts model.

I have a `:post_rate` method

```
def self.post_rate(month_start, month_end)
     where('created_at >= ? AND <= ?', month_start, month_end).map { |p| p.created_at.beginning_of_day }.uniq.size.to_f / (month_start - month_end).to_f 
end
```

This shows the percentage of days a User posted in a given time frame.

On a User show page I want to display a summary of the user's post frequency by month. I need an array that looks like:

```
['Month', 'Frequency'],
['Jan',  0.1],
['Feb',  0.5],
['Mar',  0.9],
etc..
```

(the labels and titles are needed).

How can I achieve this?

What performance considerations do I need to think about?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rails is recent enough, you can use ActiveRecord's query smarts to compile a query that does this in SQL.  You can pass a function to a GROUP BY clause via `group`:

```
where('created_at >= ? AND <= ?', month_start, month_end).group("to_char(created_at,'MONTH')").count()
```

The above works for PostgreSQL.  You may have to change the arg to `group` to get it to work with a different database.

The result will be in the form of a hash whose keys are the GROUP BY column and whose values are the counts.   You will probably need to do some munging to get the data in the format you require.

Comment: thanks michael, that's a great start. A couple of questions. How would I ensure all months are included in the array, even if they have no records. How could I divide the resulting size by the number of days. For example, March should be divided by 31 if 1 years is queried, 62 if two years are queried, etc. Thanks for your help!

Comment: These are things you would have to do with the result of that first line.  You might also consider changing the arguments to the `to_char` function to pass a numeric month.  This will make the resulting hash easier to manipulate; you can then create a new hash out of the result with word months as keys.